# GEOSEXCEPTION error message

Tags: python, django

I am quite new to the system. Another employee set up the command that I have been using and part of the return after a my usual system run query is below:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 115, in geos_version_info
if not m: raise GEOSException('Could not parse version info string "%s"' % ver)
django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string "3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921"
```

I have redownloaded GEOS, as per another suggestion. 
Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on this fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643998/geodjango-eosexception-error

Edit this file: site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py

Look for the function: geos_version_info

And change this line:

ver = geos_version().decode()

With this line:

ver = geos_version().split(' ')[0]